# SSRS 2008 R2 - Cascading parameters - Design view

Tags: parameters, ssrs-2008

So I have been tasked with modifying the Stories Overview report for TFS. I can get the report to run just fine in Preview.

In design time the cascading parameters cannot seem to see each other. Is this how it is supposed to be? Am I going to have to enter in (and modify) parameters for each dataset \ parameter as I try to to get my changes working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just filling in the design mode parameters into the dialog.